# win8.1 pro build 9431 restart every 1 hour or 2 hour

Tags: windows-8.1

I bought a new computer this week , is Acer aspire v5 with touchscreen , so when it start it shows a message saying that this version of windaws is experd ! and your computre will restart every 1 hour ther 2 hours ! 
so pleasssssse Help !

Comment: You need to provide a license key and activate Windows.

Comment: I don't have any licences key !

Comment: Then you will be unable to activate Windows and we will be unable to help you. That is the only solution we can suggest. You should purchase a Windows 8.1 Professional license key so you have one. I am going under the assumption this device was purchased used and never came with a Windows license.  If its new then the license key does exists and we can go from there

Comment: I want just to stop the restart !!

Comment: Without a license key thats not possible.

Comment: Okaythanks man for your replays ! can you please tell me where can I buy the key licences ?

Comment: You can purchase a license from a local retail location of your choice or online from Microsoft. I am just under the assumption the drive didn't come with Windows 8 originally and its used, correct me if I am wrong.  I am under the assumption your in a region where this is normal.  The actual laptop you have should have came with Windows 8, so use the recovery image if thats the case, this will allow you to activate Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The Preview expired January 15th, 2014.Now Windows reboots every 2 hours.

To fix it, update to the Windows 8.1 Final:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-preview